# Python 2.7 / App Engine - TypeError: is_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, typeerror

The following code is close to what I am using without getting too long.  I get the error `TypeError: is_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.  To my eyes I am only passing 2 arguments.  So where is the third argument coming from?

models/MyModel.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MyModel(db.model):
    a = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    b = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    c = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Update:
    def is_valid(x, y)
        myquery = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Valid WHERE value = :1' x)
        v = myquery.get()

        if v.something == y:
            yet_more_stuff
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
```

controllers/WebHandler.py

```
import webapp2
from models.MyModel import Update

class WebHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        var_x = "string"
        var_y = "string"
        z = Update()
        if z.is_valid(var_x, var_y): <----- line error occurs
            do_some_stuff
        else
            do_some_other_stuff
```

It is probably something simple but after coding for 18 hours today my brain has turned into oatmeal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

You have two solutions:

- add an argument representing instance in the method definition (name it `self` for consistency), or
- use `staticmethod` decorator on the method.

### Explanation and examples

This line:

```
def is_valid(x, y):
```

means that when the method is called, `x` is the class instance and `y` is the argument. If you wanted to accept two arguments (*and* the instance itself), your line should look like that:

```
def is_valid(self, x, y)
```

But because you are not making any actions on the instance itself, you can also use `staticmethod` decorator:

```
@staticmethod
def is_valid(x, y):
```

This will get rid of the instance being passed in the arguments and you will only receive the remaining arguments.

Comment: Or, even better, get rid of the class altogether since it's not encapsulating any data and serves no purpose I can see.

Comment: @Wooble: Maybe it is meant to serve some purpose in the future and the OP does not want to change the API when it does?

Comment: Tadeck and Shay below are both right.  I did use the self last night, but in my tiredness I was also passing self from WebHandler which gave me a different TypeError along the lines of trying to pass a WebHandler Instance to Update Instance.

I don't know why I didn't think of `@staticmethod` last night but you are correct that works also.  I am giving you the acepted answer due to adding that and going into a bit more detail.

Thanks to both Tadeck and @Shay-Erlichmen

Answer (score 7):

change the code to `def is_valid(self, x, y)`